# How to refresh a dynamic TableView Footer (Not Section Footer) using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, tableview

I have a TableView footerView with two labels that can hold multiple lines.
I'm using this code in viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    label1.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.frame.size.width - Constant.footerMarginSpace
    label2.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.frame.size.width - Constant.footerMarginSpace
    footerView.setNeedsLayout()
    footerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    footerView.frame.size.height = footerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    tableView.tableFooterView =  footerView
}
```

This is working fine (the labels will eventually spread over multiples lines and the size of the view is adjusting) when the labels value are set before the view is shown, but If I update their content after, the view won't update its layout, even when using tableView.reloadData().

If I push another view on top of my view, and dismiss it, the layout will be correct.

What is the proper way to update the layout and size of my TableView footer ?

Comment: try tableView.tableFooterView.layoutIfNeeded() after editing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to calculate how many lines you need based on your data and return the correct height using
[tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview)

This method will be called to layout your tableview when the `reloadData` is called.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread.
So if you wanna go thr `heightForFooterInSection`, you could use the last sections footer.
If you wanna use the table footer, TableView headers and footers sort of behave like Cells. You should be able to set up the correct LayoutConstraints like you do with a normal Cell. Then the footer should behave like any other automatic sized tableview Cell.
Like a Cell, the footer should do it's own layout.

Comment: But the last section footer is behaving differently, it's sticky